# NestJS - How does AuthGuard knows about the Passport Strategy?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, passport.js

I am having a hard time figuring out the NestJS and PassportJS combination when it comes to the authentication/authorization process, and I am a type of developer who does not like magic when it comes to developing.

##### Issue

Basically, my goal is to understand how does AuthGuard knows about the Passport Strategy being implemented in the project, it could be Local Strategy, or any other, for example JWT Strategy. I have two modules **AuthModule** and **UserModule** and this is how the **AuthService** looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private usersService: UsersService){}

    async validateUser(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.usersService.findOne(username);

        if (user && user.password === password) {
            const {password, ...result} = user
            return result
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

**UserService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

export type User = any;

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

    private readonly users = [
        {
            userId: 1,
            username: 'John Marston',
            password: 'rdr1',
        },
        {
            userId: 2,
            username: 'Arthur Morgan',
            password: 'rdr2',
        },
    ]

    async findOne(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
        return this.users.find(user => user.username === username)
    }
}
```

##### Passport

After installing the packages for Passport and NestJS, I imported **PassportModule** and implemented the **LocalStrategy** and also imported that strategy as a provider inside the **AuthModule**

**LocalStrategy**:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        super()
    }

    async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);

        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule, PassportModule],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

##### Login route

```
import { Controller, Post, Request, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
}
```

I understand everything up until this part. I do also understand how we get the req.user object etc. but I do not understand how does the **AuthGuard** knows, that we implemented Passport Local Strategy. Does it look through the files (sorry if this is dumb to say) and finds where we imported the **PassportModule** and also where we implemented the **LocalStrategy** since that class extends the PassportStrategy class, but also important to say, imported from passport-local.

I do understand that **AuthGuard** is a special type of Guard, but I am not sure if I understand it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I have a rather good article on this](https://dev.to/nestjs/setting-up-sessions-with-nestjs-passport-and-redis-210), but to put it on StackOverflow too:

Each `Strategy` from a `passport-*` package has a `name` property that is the name for the strategy. For `passport-local` that `name` is `local`. For `passport-jwt`, that name is `'jwt'`. This doesn't always line up one to one, but each package should document what its name for passport is. This is the name that gets passed to `passport.use()` and `passport.authenticate()`. `passport.use` is called via some clever code in the `PassportStrategy` class from `@nestjs/passport` to register the strategy with passport and `passport.authenticate` is called inside of the `AuthGuard()` using either the global default set via the passport module's options or via the mixin's parameters, like `local` in your code sample.